# Wordpress - hide div with class in admin interface

Tags: wordpress, interface, admin

I tried this code which should hide the div with class .my_class for all users except admin, however I still see the div as a normal user.

```
function hide_form_result_buttons() {
if (!current_user_can('manage_options') && !is_admin()) {
echo '\<style type="text/css"\> .my_class { display: none !important; } \</style\>';
}
}
add_action('wp_head', 'hide_form_result_buttons');
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_form_result_buttons');
```

Answer (score 0):

This code function :)

```
function hide_form_result_buttons() {
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
                var formResultButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".form-result-buttons");
                for (var i = 0; i < formResultButtons.length; i++) {
                    formResultButtons[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'hide_form_result_buttons');
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_form_result_buttons');
```